# AWS Amplify lambda function unable to access a mutation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

Following [this documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/graphql-from-nodejs/q/platform/js) to build a Lambda function to do some admin-type stuff for an Amplify-based app.  I have Cognito log in set up for the client side, and that all works. I've added the function (transcript lost) and then modified it:

```
> amplify update function
? Select which capability you want to update: Lambda function (serverless function)
? Select the Lambda function you want to update categoryAdder
? Do you want to update the Lambda function permissions to access other resources in this
project? Yes
? Select the category api
Api category has a resource called todoexample
? Select the operations you want to permit for todoexample create, read, update, delete

You can access the following resource attributes as environment variables from your Lambda
 function
        API_TODOEXAMPLE_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
        API_TODOEXAMPLE_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
? Do you want to invoke this function on a recurring schedule? No
? Do you want to configure Lambda layers for this function? No
? Do you want to edit the local lambda function now? No
```

Here is the GraphQL schema:

```
type Todo @model
@auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, delete, update] }])
{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String
    category: Category
}

type Category @model
@auth (rules: [
    { allow: private, operations: [read] },
    { allow: private, provider: iam }
])
{
    id: ID!
    category: String!
}

type Mutation
{
    addCategory(category: String!): Category @function(name: "categoryAdder-${env}")
}
```

The idea is that only the Lambda function can run the `addCategory` mutation.

Here's the code:

```js
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    API_TODOEXAMPLE_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
    API_TODOEXAMPLE_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
    ENV
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

const https = require('https')
const urlParse = require('url').URL
const appsyncUrl = process.env.API_TODOEXAMPLE_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
const region = process.env.REGION
const endpoint = new urlParse(appsyncUrl).hostname.toString()
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
require('es6-promise').polyfill()
require('isomorphic-fetch')

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const mutation = `
  mutation addCategory($category: String!) {
    addCategory(category: $category) {
      id
      category
    }
  }
`

  AWS.config.update({
    region,
    credentials: new AWS.Credentials(
      process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
    ),
  })
  const credentials = AWS.config.credentials

  const req = new AWS.HttpRequest(appsyncUrl, region)
  req.method = 'POST'
  req.path = '/graphql'
  req.headers.host = endpoint
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.body = JSON.stringify({
    query: mutation,
    operationName: 'addCategory',
    variables: { category: 'Cats' },
  })

  const signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req, 'appsync', true)
  signer.addAuthorization(credentials, AWS.util.date.getDate())

  console.log(`About to do promise...`)
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`About to do https.request...`)
    const httpRequest = https.request({ ...req, host: endpoint }, (result) => {
      console.log(`In https.request callback`)
      result.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`In result.on callback, data is`, data.toString())
        resolve(JSON.parse(data.toString()))
      })
    })

    console.log(`About to do httpRequest.write`)
    httpRequest.write(req.body)
    httpRequest.end()
  })
  console.log(`Returning data`, data)

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: data,
  }
}
```

The error I get is "Not Authorized to access addCategory on type Mutation".

Any clues appreciated!